# How to create remote JIRA Issue with ruby-jira Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to use the [jira-ruby](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby) Gem to interface with a remote JIRA server with 5.x REST API.

Accessing data on the server works well, but it seems I can not create a new JIRA issue remotely. The Gem's documentation is minimal, and there are no examples provided.

Can somebody provide a working example on:

- how to create a remote JIRA Issue with `ruby-jira`
- how to attach a file to an existing Issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To create new JIRA Issue use:

**CODE:**

```
issue = client.Issue.build
issue.save({"fields"=>{"summary"=>"blarg from in example.rb","project"=>{"id"=>"10001"},"issuetype"=>{"id"=>"3"}}})
issue.fetch
pp issue
```

Or

You can try REST APIs to create JIRA Issue.

**Using IDs**

The first example creates an issue by specifying the project ID and issue type ID.
Request

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

**Data**

Here's the JSON:

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "id": "10110"
       },
       "summary": "No REST for the Wicked.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using ids for projects and issue types using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "id": "1"
       }
   }
}
```

**Response**

The response provides the issue ID, issue key, and the URL to the issue (which can then be used to GET additional data, PUT updates, etc).

```
{
   "id":"39001",
   "key":"TEST-102",
    "self":"http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-102"
}
```

**Using Project Key and Field Names**

Alternatively, you can create an issue by specifying the project key and field names.
Request

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

**Data**

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
   "id":"39000",
   "key":"TEST-101",
    "self":"http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-101"
}
```

Source: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs

Comment: You might have to uncomment this code from example.rb in gem. Am not sure why its commented out there.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.   My code looked very similar, but I kept getting `false` as the result of the `issue.save`.  I found the problem - the `priority` id which I provided was a number instead of a string. That caused the save to be rejected.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to attach a file to the newly created issue?

Comment: Sorry bro.. I dont have an example.. If I get some solution def. will share with you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - the docs are terribly unclear - as is the code itself.